# Error when importing .CSV file into DataGrid

Tags: c++, wpf, csv

I am trying to get data from .CSV file into DataGrid in a WPF application.

Here is my code. The problem is that when I click on the button and select the file, the code throws an exception "Syntax error in PropertyPath 'Unmatched parenthesis ".

What is wrong in this code ?

```
    private void OnImport(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       try
        {
            lFnLoadFileData();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    void lFnLoadFileData()
    {
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog lObjFileDlge = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            lObjFileDlge.Filter = "CSV Files|*.xlsx";
            lObjFileDlge.FilterIndex = 1;
            lObjFileDlge.Multiselect = false;
            string fName = "";
            bool? lBlnUserclicked = lObjFileDlge.ShowDialog();
            if (lBlnUserclicked != null || lBlnUserclicked == true)
            {
                fName = lObjFileDlge.FileName;
            }
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fName) == true)
            {
                // FileStream lObjFileStream = lObjFileDlge.File.OpenRead();
                StreamReader lObjStreamReader = new StreamReader(fName);
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(lObjStreamReader.ToString());
                lFnGenerateData(lObjStreamReader);
                lObjStreamReader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    void lFnGenerateData(StreamReader aReader)
    {
        try
        {
            bool lBlnIsColumns = true;
            string[] lArrCols = null;
            List<Contacts> lstPersonalList = new List<Contacts>();
            dataGrid1.Columns.Clear();
            while (aReader.Peek() > 0)
            {
                string lStrLine = aReader.ReadLine();
                if (lStrLine == null)
                    break;
                if (lStrLine.Trim() == "")
                    continue;
                string[] lArrStrCells = null;
                lArrStrCells = lStrLine.Split(';');
                if (lArrStrCells == null)
                    continue;
                if (lBlnIsColumns)
                {
                    lArrCols = lArrStrCells;
                    foreach (string lStrCell in lArrStrCells)
                    {
                        DataGridTextColumn lDGCol = new DataGridTextColumn();
                        lDGCol.Header = lStrCell;
                        lDGCol.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding(lStrCell);
                        dataGrid1.Columns.Add(lDGCol);
                    }
                    lBlnIsColumns = false;
                    continue;
                }
                if (lArrCols == null)
                    continue;

                int lIntColID = 0;
                Contacts objPersonalInfo = new Contacts();
                objPersonalInfo.ContactName = lArrStrCells[0];
                objPersonalInfo.ContactNumber = lArrStrCells[1];
                objPersonalInfo.Status  = lArrStrCells[2];

                lstPersonalList.Add(objPersonalInfo);
            }
            aReader.Close();
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = lstPersonalList;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is likely caused by this line. You are trying to bind to an invalid property name?

```
lDGCol.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding(lStrCell);
```

Comment: I dont know Sir . i have did alot of search to solve. what should i do ?

Comment: You must ensure that lStrCell is always a valid property name.